# How do you read and print a chunked HTTP response using java.net.http as chunks arrive?

Tags: java, http, reactive, java-http-client

Java 11 introduces a new package, `java.net.http`, for making HTTP requests. For general usage, it's pretty straight forward.

My question is: how do I use `java.net.http` to handle chunked responses as each chunk is received by the client?

`java.http.net` contains a reactive `BodySubscriber` which appears to be what I want, but I can't find an example of how it's used.

#### http_get_demo.py

Below is a python implementation that prints chunks as they arrive, I'd like to the same thing with java.net.http:

```
import argparse
import requests


def main(url: str):
    with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
        for c in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1):
            print(c.decode("UTF-8"), end="")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="Read from a URL and print as text as chunks arrive")
    parser.add_argument('url', type=str, help="A URL to read from")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    main(args.url)
```

#### HttpGetDemo.java

Just for completeness, here's a simple example of making a blocking request using java.net.http:

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;

public class HttpGetDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    var request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(URI.create(args[0]))
            .build();

    var bodyHandler = HttpResponse.BodyHandlers
            .ofString();

    var client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    var response = client.send(request, bodyHandler);
    System.out.println(response.body());

  }
}
```

#### HttpAsyncGetDemo.java

And here's the example making an non-blocking/async request:

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;

/**
 * ReadChunked
 */
public class HttpAsyncGetDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    var request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(URI.create(args[0]))
            .build();

    var bodyHandler = HttpResponse.BodyHandlers
            .ofString();

    var client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

    client.sendAsync(request, bodyHandler)
            .thenApply(HttpResponse::body)
            .thenAccept(System.out::println)
            .join();

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @pavel and @chegar999 for their partial answers. They led me to my solution.

#### Overview

The solution I came up with is below. Basically, the solution is to use a custom `java.net.http.HttpResponse.BodySubscriber`. A BodySubscriber contains reactive methods (onSubscribe, onNext, onError, and onComplete) and a getBody method that basically returns a java [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) that will eventually produce the body of the HTTP request. Once you have your BodySubscriber in hand you can use it like:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
    .uri(URI.create(uri))
    .build();

return client.sendAsync(request, responseInfo -> new StringSubscriber())
    .whenComplete((r, t) -> System.out.println("--- Status code " + r.statusCode()))
    .thenApply(HttpResponse::body);
```

Note the line:

`client.sendAsync(request, responseInfo -> new StringSubscriber())`

That's where we register our custom BodySubscriber; in this case, my custom class is named `StringSubscriber`.

#### CustomSubscriber.java

This is a complete working example. Using Java 11, you can run it without compiling it. Just past it into a file named `CustomSubscriber.java`, then run the command `java CustomSubscriber <some url>`. It prints the contents of each chunk as it arrives. It also collects them and returns them as the body when the response has completed.

```
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse.BodyHandlers;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse.BodySubscriber;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.Flow;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomSubscriber {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    CustomSubscriber cs = new CustomSubscriber();
    String body = cs.get(args[0]).join();
    System.out.println("--- Response body:\n: ..." + body + "...");
  }

  public CompletableFuture<String> get(String uri) {
    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        .uri(URI.create(uri))
        .build();

    return client.sendAsync(request, responseInfo -> new StringSubscriber())
        .whenComplete((r, t) -> System.out.println("--- Status code " + r.statusCode()))
        .thenApply(HttpResponse::body);
  }

  static class StringSubscriber implements BodySubscriber<String> {

    final CompletableFuture<String> bodyCF = new CompletableFuture<>();
    Flow.Subscription subscription;
    List<ByteBuffer> responseData = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public CompletionStage<String> getBody() {
      return bodyCF;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Flow.Subscription subscription) {
      this.subscription = subscription;
      subscription.request(1); // Request first item
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(List<ByteBuffer> buffers) {
      System.out.println("-- onNext " + buffers);
      try {
        System.out.println("\tBuffer Content:\n" + asString(buffers));
      } 
      catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("\tUnable to print buffer content");
      }
      buffers.forEach(ByteBuffer::rewind); // Rewind after reading
      responseData.addAll(buffers);
      subscription.request(1); // Request next item
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
      bodyCF.completeExceptionally(throwable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
      bodyCF.complete(asString(responseData));
    }

    private String asString(List<ByteBuffer> buffers) {
      return new String(toBytes(buffers), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }

    private byte[] toBytes(List<ByteBuffer> buffers) {
      int size = buffers.stream()
          .mapToInt(ByteBuffer::remaining)
          .sum();
      byte[] bs = new byte[size];
      int offset = 0;
      for (ByteBuffer buffer : buffers) {
        int remaining = buffer.remaining();
        buffer.get(bs, offset, remaining);
        offset += remaining;
      }
      return bs;
    }

  }
}
```

#### Trying it out

To test this solution, you'll need a server that sends a response that uses `Transfer-encoding: chunked` and sends it slow enough to watch the chunks arrive. I've created one at https://github.com/hohonuuli/demo-chunk-server but you can spin it up using Docker like so:

`docker run -p 8080:8080 hohonuuli/demo-chunk-server`

Then run the CustomSubscriber.java code using `java CustomSubscriber.java http://localhost:8080/chunk/10`

Answer (score 4):

The python code does not ensure that the response body data is made available one [HTTP chunk](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-4.1) at a time. It just provides small amounts of data to the application, thus reducing the amount of memory consumed at the application level ( it could be buffered lower in the stack ). The Java 11 HTTP Client supports streaming through one of the streaming body handlers, `HttpResponse.BodyHandlers`:  `ofInputStream`, `ofByteArrayConsumer`, `ofLines`, etc.

Or write your own handler / subscriber as demonstrated:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiaC0QMLz5Y

Answer (score 2):

You can print `ByteBuffer`s as they come, but there's no guarantee that a `ByteBuffer` corresponds to a chunk. Chunks are handled by the stack. One `ByteBuffer` slice will be pushed for every chunk - but if there isn’t enough space remaining in the buffer, then a partial chunk will be pushed. All the consumer sees is a stream of `ByteBuffer`s that contain the data.
So what you can do is print those `ByteBuffer`s as they come, but you have no guarantee that they correspond exactly one chunk each as was sent by the server.

Note: If the body of your request is text based, then you can use
`BodyHandlers.fromLineSubscriber(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber)` with a custom `Subscriber<String>` that will print each line as it comes.
The `BodyHandlers.fromLineSubscriber` does the hard word of decoding bytes into chars using the charset indicated in the response headers, buffering bytes if needed until they can be decoded (a ByteBuffer might end in the middle of an encoding sequence if the text contains chars encoded over multiple bytes), and splitting them at the line boundary. The Subscriber::onNext method will be invoked once for each line in the text. See https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.html#fromLineSubscriber(java.util.concurrent.Flow.Subscriber) for more info.

Comment: `Flow.Subscription#request(long)` must be called in `Subscriber#onNext(String)` and `Subscriber#onSubscribe(Flow.Subscription)` to make it work. If you don't do that, it will remain blocked.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a new Java library to address this kind of requirements
RxSON: https://github.com/rxson/rxson
It utilizes the JsonPath wit RxJava to read JSON streamed chunks from the response as soon as they arrive, and parse them to java objects.

Example:

```
String serviceURL = "https://think.cs.vt.edu/corgis/datasets/json/airlines/airlines.json";
   HttpRequest req = HttpRequest.newBuilder(URI.create(serviceURL)).GET().build();
   RxSON rxson = new RxSON.Builder().build();

   String jsonPath = "$[*].Airport.Name";
   Flowable<String> airportStream = rxson.create(String.class, req, jsonPath);
   airportStream
       .doOnNext(it -> System.out.println("Received new item: " + it))
       //Just for test
       .toList()
       .blockingGet();
```

Comment: did the original question even mention JSON as the content type of the responses?

Answer (score 0):

This is a trivial solution based on chegar999's answer:

```
httpClient.send(httpRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofByteArrayConsumer((final Optional<byte[]> receivedBytesOptional) -> {
    if (receivedBytesOptional.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Done");
    } else {
        final byte[] receivedBytes = receivedBytesOptional.get();
        final String received = new String(receivedBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.println("Received: " + received);
    }
}));
```

It works as long as your multi-byte characters aren't divided into two chunks (otherwise, use `java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder#decode()`).

In my humble opinion, it's easier and less error prone than using a custom subscriber, which is more suitable in cases that require more flexibility.