# How do I read chunked HTTP responses on jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, chunked-encoding, http-chunked

I am using jmeter to send a HTTP POST request. the server responds with a chunked http response 200 ok and I need to parse the initial chunk. However jmeter waits for all the response chunks.
I tried with the http sampler and http raw request sampler. In both cases the chunks are not parsed individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved only by using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and custom [Groovy scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) (or alternatively writing a brand new [JMeter Plugin](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_tutorial.html))

Example code you can use as the basis can be found in [How do you read and print a chunked HTTP response using java.net.http as chunks arrive? answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53057925/2897748)

Comment: The above sample code works fine when run with Java11. However when i tried to run it from jmeter using a JSR Sampler (groovy compiler), the request is sent but there is not response detected by the code even though the response actually is sent. (could see from wireshark trace).